# $x^{x\sqrt{x}} = (x\sqrt{x})^x$: How can I correctly explain the existence of the root $x=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a fairly well-known equation: $x^{x\sqrt{x}} = (x\sqrt{x})^x$

$$x^{x\sqrt{x}} = (x\sqrt{x})^x \iff x^{x^{3/2}}=(x^{3/2})^x \iff x^{x^{3/2}}=(x^{3x/2})$$

Take logarithms on both sides:

$$x^{3/2}\ln{x}=\frac{3x}{2}\ln{x}$$

From here it is quite easy to get one of the roots $x=\frac{9}{4}$ and $x=0$, if we divide both sides by $\ln{x}$.

However, why is $0$ not suitable, but $1$ is suitable?

Comment: That's because the function $\ln(x)$ is only defined when $x > 0$. Moreover, $\ln(x)$ vanishes at $x = 1$, whence we conclude that $x = 1$ is also a solution.

Comment: If you believe $0^0 = 1$, as I do, then $x=0$ is a solution to the original equation.  (however, often $0^0$ is considered undefined and so it would not be a solution.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you used the logarithm function, you supposed that $x>0$. Indeed, $\ln$ is only defined on $]0,+\infty[$, which is why the solution $x=0$ should be excluded from your proof.

If you want your proof to be complete, you need to check if $0$ was a solution - here, we can see that it was (if you consider that $0^0$ is defined)

You were also wondering why the solution $x=1$ doesn't appear; it's because dividing by $\ln x$ means $\ln x \neq 0$, i.e. $x \neq 1$. Again, you need to check if $x=1$ is a solution afterwards - and it is!

Comment: Thank you! All the same, I don't teach the whole theory because of this, such simple mistakes appear =)

Comment: If $0^0$ is undefined then $x=0$ is not a solution.